# An elementary graph theory question

Tags: graph-theory

In college I've stumbled across the following:

Let $G$ be a graph defined by:
$$V(G) = \{v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4\}$$
$$E(G) = \{v_1v_2,v_2v_3,v_3v_4,v_2v_4\}$$

Define $L(G)$ to be a new graph such that:
$$V(L(G)) = E(G)$$
$$ab\in E(L(G))\Leftrightarrow a=mn\space\And\space b=np(m\ne p)$$

What are the vertices of $L(G)$ and its edges?

Sorry if my latex is bad, I just read couple of things online to be able to write this.

I suspect that maybe each vertex isn't an ordinary vertex but a pair, what do you think?

Comment: What is $mn$ and $np$?

Comment: @FedericoFallucca it didn't say anything other then this, this is the full question.

Answer (score 2):

$L(G)$ is the [line graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_graph) of $G$.  The vertices of $L(G)$ are the edges of $G$ and two vertices of $L(G)$ are adjacent iff the corresponding edges on $G$ have a vertex in common.  Re-read the definition given in the exercise now, and you'll see that it is describing the line graph.

With this understanding, you should have no trouble completing the exercise.

Comment: Cool, but in our college book we don't have anything called a line graph, is it maybe a called a path in other places?

Comment: @I'mNewHere I don't think so.  They're just describing the line graph in the exercise, without giving its name.

Comment: well okay, I'll try my best to find the edges and vertices